# Quickblox data security

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption, quickblox

I am developing a chat application using **Quickblox** SDK. I have been asked to hash user's **password** using **MD5** when sending requests to server (login, signup ,modify profile ...). But i want to know if this is necessary since it may have been implemented in the SDK itself. I have been searching through **Quickblox** documentation but i did not find any hint about **data security**.

Should i hash password when sending requests? Does **Quickblox** SDK handle password hashing when it comes to requests exchanging between client and server?

Comment: 1. MD5 is not encryption since it can not be decrypted, it is a hash function. 2. MD5 should not be used in new work because it is no longer considered secure, rather use a more current and secure hash such as SHA256. 3. A simple way to determine if the SDK hashes the password is to run Charles Proxy and look at what is being sent over the network.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question and used the right terms. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickblox uses HTTPS encryption for all requests, you can see this by looking into debug console.

Comment: That's right, someone sniffing the network traffic will not be able to read it.